# How to create element li img tag in ul tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to create element li img tag in ul tag using javascript ?

I want to create

```
<li id="123">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Loading_bar.gif"/>
</li>
```

inner

```
<ul id="placehere">
```

But not work, How can i do that ?

https://jsfiddle.net/btz69dyk/2/

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){

var elem = document.createElement("li");
elem.setAttribute("id", "123");

var elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.setAttribute("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Loading_bar.gif");
elem.setAttribute("height", "");
elem.setAttribute("width", "");
elem.setAttribute("alt", "Flower");
document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(elem);
}
</script>
<ul id="placehere">
</ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is these 4 lines

```
var elem = document.createElement("li");
elem.setAttribute("id", "123");

var elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.setAttribute("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Loading_bar.gif");
```

here you are creating the same `elem` element again with same variable name so `li` is lost

change it to

```
var elem1 = document.createElement("li");
elem1.setAttribute("id", "123");

var elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.setAttribute("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Loading_bar.gif");
elem.setAttribute("height", "");
elem.setAttribute("width", "");
elem.setAttribute("alt", "Flower");
document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(elem1);
elem1.appendChild(elem);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Append `image` element to `li` element first and then append `li` element in `ul` element.

In your example, you are creating elements in same variable(`elem`) hence second element will over-ride the earlier created element(variable will hold later element). Append `image` element to `li` element before updating it in `DOM`, it will trouble `DOM` structure only once..

Try this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var li_elem = document.createElement("li");
  li_elem.setAttribute("id", "123");
  var img_elem = document.createElement("img");
  img_elem.setAttribute("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Loading_bar.gif");
  img_elem.setAttribute("height", "");
  img_elem.setAttribute("width", "");
  img_elem.setAttribute("alt", "Flower");
  li_elem.appendChild(img_elem);
  document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(li_elem);
}
```

```html
<ul id="placehere">
</ul>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/btz69dyk/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var listEle = document.createElement("li");
listEle.setAttribute("id", "123");

var elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.setAttribute("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Loading_bar.gif");
elem.setAttribute("height", "");
elem.setAttribute("width", "");
elem.setAttribute("alt", "Flower");
document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(listEle).appendChild(elem);
```